# how to build a tree in r?

Tags: r, classification, ctree

I'm working on a student performance dataset and I get this message error

> Error in trafo(data = data, numeric_trafo = numeric_trafo, factor_trafo = factor_trafo,  :
> data class “character” is not supported
> In addition: Warning message:
> In storage.mode(RET@predict_trafo) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

from this code, and I don't know why?

```
set.seed(1)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(d2),replace = TRUE ,prob = c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- d2[ind==1,]
testData <- d2[ind==2,]
library(party)
myFormula <- higher~G1+G2+G3
d2_ctree <- ctree(myFormula, data=trainData)
table(predict(d2_ctree),trainData$higher)
```

Comment: unfortunately you did not supply data of d2. From the error it should be clear, that you have some variable as character when it should be factor (most probable) or maybe numeric (integer/double).... many algorithms/functions do not work with character but they work when converitng these columns to factors... hope this helps

Comment: You didn't supply d2 object . However , i think this example may help you : https://rpubs.com/njvijay/14899

Answer (score 0):

An example with iris data ( as you didn't give `d2` data ) :

```
library(party)
set.seed(1234) #To get reproducible result
ind <- sample(2,nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- iris[ind==1,]
testData <- iris[ind==2,]
myFormula <- Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
d2_ctree <- ctree(myFormula, data=trainData)
table(predict(d2_ctree),trainData$Species)
plot(d2_ctree)
```

Source : [source](https://rpubs.com/njvijay/14899)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert **all** nonnumerical columns to numeric.

```
d2$higher = factor(d2$higher,levels = c("Label1","Label2","Label3"), 
                    labels = c(1, 2, 3))
```